# Serial.write(buf, len) error. How to remove an error and pass an array of bytes?

Tags: serial

```
int angleServo1,angleServo2 = 0;
const int axisX=A0; // ось Х подключена к A0
const int axisY=A1; // ось Y подключена к A1
int valX, valY = 0; // переменные для хранения значений осей
int datos[3];
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() 
 {
   Serial.begin(9600);
 }

void loop() 
 {
      valX = analogRead(axisX); // значение оси Х
      valY = analogRead(axisY); // значение оси Y
      // масштабируем значение к интервалу 0-180
      angleServo1=map(valX,0,800,100,-100);
      angleServo2=map(valY,0,810,100,-100);

       datos[0] = angleServo1;
       datos[1] = angleServo2;
       Serial.write(datos, sizeof(datos));
       delay(100);
}
```

error: no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::write(int [3], unsigned int)'

how to remove an error and pass an array of bytes?

Comment: byte datos[3]; changed, I will test the code. I'm not sure that it will work. Because the byte of small value.

Comment: it is telling you that `HardwareSerial::write()` does not have a function that will accept two arguments where the first one is an array of integers and the second one is an unsigned integer ..... i think that HardwareSerial::write() only has a function that accepts one argument that is an integer, not an array

Comment: try this: Serial.print(datos);

Comment: See: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/3d09a51bd20f095e1354243e6d8addedfcb6001e/cores/arduino/Print.h#L56-L59

Comment: @jsotola, what? write(int)? there is `write(byte)` and `write(buff[], size)`

Comment: did not word that correctly ... i think that the brain was in neutral ... the serial.write() accepts an array of bytes, not an array of integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to send data to computer processing or print them for user to read? Functions `write` send raw data. To print the data to Serial monitor `print` and `println` functions are used.

There are two `write` functions. First sends one byte. Second sends array of bytes. There is no write function to send array of ints. You could cast the array of ints to array of bytes to send the array as raw bytes for processing on the receiving side. But then you first should perhaps send to the receiving side some control data about the data package.

```
  Serial.write((byte*) datos, sizeof(datos));
```

If you want to print numbers to Serial Monitor, the `print` functions have variants which take a number and convert it to string. But there is no `print` function to print an array of numbers. You must print them one by one in a for loop. And put some separator between them (coma, space, new line).

Comment: note: sizeof returns the size of the array in bytes